# import R cannot be resolved when i tried importing R.Layout.activity

Tags: android, android-layout

When I used `R.layout.activity` in `setContentView` it says it cannot be resolved.

So, I tried importing it from  `R.layout` but then it says

> import R cannot be resolved.

```
package com.example.trial;
import com.example.trial.util.SystemUiHider;
import com.example.trial.R; 
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Trial extends Activity{    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Trial.this, second.class));
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove:**

```
import R.layout.activity

import android.R
```

**If necessary add:**

```
import your.package.R; //(shouldn't be needed though)
```

**Do:**

Clean & build

**Explanation**

When you import android.R you import the platform resources instead of your app resources.

Comment: i tried importing my own package but still no result...

Comment: Update your code with how it looks now.

Comment: after removing the line you mentioned another error appears where it fails to resolve the button i have used.

Comment: If you used android.R for your button ID refer to it as android.R.button1, I.e. Use the fully qualified class name for android.R. Or change your xml file not to use Android.R, remember to clean and rebuild.

Comment: k. if i import android.R is there no way making my "activity" avialable to it?

Comment: Imports are just a short hand, you don't actually need to import anything you could always write the full class name. You can always refer to a class like this: package.name.ClassName, so you could refer to your own R com.example.trail.R and the android R android.R, in your code.

Comment: May be, you got an error in your resource files (filename is wrong or resource not found). If you got the error, IDEA doesn't generate the R file

Comment: thank you johanshogun indeed you cleared my concept.

Comment: i removed import android.R; and   i tried referring to my package but it says """ the import com.example.trial cannot be resolved                                  dont include android.R here;use a fully qualified name for each usage instead"""'

Comment: Show your updated code and xml file.

Comment: i have edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

### Why This

**`R`** is auto generated resource in android project some times it happens don't exactly know why but have you try build automatically option from project

So for the first issue, if you see at the import section

```
import android.R;
```

*delete it.*

For the second issue, you have to solve your errors at the XML files first, and then when you build your project, your **R** error will be gone. (You may have to **clean your project first**).

```
Clean-Rebuild-Restart
```

Please read [A comprehensive troubleshooting guide for Android's R cannot](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/) be resolved error .I hope it will helps you.

So finally,

```
package com.example.trial;

import com.example.trial.util.SystemUiHider;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Trial extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Button tut1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), second.class));

        }
    });

}}
```